# Как продолжить код после блоки if __name__ == '__main__'

Tags: python, multiprocessing, main

Мне нужно, чтобы код, который находится после блока `if __name__ == '__main__'` запускался, только после того, как блок `if __name__ == '__main__'` выполнит свои задачи. Но я столкнулся с тем, что в начале у меня весь код выполняется несколько раз, а затем только блок `if __name__ == '__main__'`. Подскажите, как мне правильно нужно реализовать свой код, чтобы добиться того, чего я хочу?

```
import multiprocessing

result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def save(link):
    return 9

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_proc = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(n_proc) as pool:
        for res in pool.map(save, result):
            result.append(res)
    print(result)

print("OK")
```

В итоге я получаю следующий вывод:

```
OK
OK
OK
OK
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
OK
```

Внесу поправку! При изменении строки `for res in pool.map(save, result):`  на `for res in range(0, len(result)):` я получаю другой вывод?

Вот полный код:

```
import multiprocessing

result = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
def save(res):
    result[res].append("Да")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_proc = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(n_proc) as pool:
        for res in range(0, len(result)):
            save(res)
    print(result)

print("OK")
```

И я получаю вот такой вывод:

```
[[1, 'Да'], [2, 'Да'], [3, 'Да'], [4, 'Да'], [5, 'Да']]
OK
```

Как это может быть связано? И почему так получается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Весь код снаружи блока `if __name__ == '__main__'` у вас выполняется в каждом новом созданном процессе, из-за этого и выводит "ОК" столько раз, сколько у вас ядер (+ 1 раз в первоначальном процессе после вывода результата). Чтобы выводило один раз, выводите внутри этого блока после вывода результата.

> Но я столкнулся с тем, что в начале у меня весь код выполняется несколько раз, а затем только блок `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

Вообще-то нет, у вас начинает выполняется код модуля в первоначальном процессе, в том числе начинает выполняться блок `if __name__ == '__main__'`, потом спавнятся рабочие процессы, в каждом из них код вашего модуля импортируется, из-за этого выполняется все кроме кода в блоке `if __name__ == '__main__'`, и потом первоначальные процесс из новых процессов вызывает функцию `save`.

Код с исправлением, плюс добавил принты, чтобы был лучше виден процесс выполнения:

```
import multiprocessing

result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


def save(link):
    print("save", link)
    return 9


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("if __name__ == '__main__'")
    n_proc = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(n_proc) as pool:
        for res in pool.map(save, result):
            result.append(res)
    print(result)
    print("OK")
```

Вывод:

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
save 1
save 2
save 4
save 3
save 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
OK
```

---

Повторное выполнение кода снаружи `if __name__ == '__main__'` кстати у меня сейчас не воспроизводится, возможно зависит от версии Python или еще чего-то, но я помню, что когда-то сталкивался с такой проблемой.

Comment: А если у меня в коде multiprocessing запускается внутри функции, то мне все что находится не в этой функции, после ее вызова нужно тоже в блок `if __name__ == '__main__'` ставить?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста снова мой вопрос. Я там внес изменения и не пойму в чем закономерность, при изменении буквально одной строки я получаю совсем другой вывод. Как это может быть связано?

Comment: @Gothed у каждого процесса своя память и свой собственный список results, никак не связанный со списком из исходного процесса. Нужно или через return результат возвращать (тогда Python сам вернет результат в исходный процесс), или использовать средства межпроцессного взаимодействия, такие как очереди и пайпы: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes . А вообще это уже отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!